# DiGiorgi Nash Moser Reference request

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Before the celebrated work of Nash and DiGiorgi, there were partial proofs of the regularity results known before, especially in 2-D.

I am looking for 2-D results of the regularity which predated Nash and DiGiorgi. Could someone let me know where these were proved?

Comment: Have you seen [this related Question at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/203305/nashs-proof-of-de-giorgi-nash-moser-theorem)?  It links to a pay-walled paper "A new proof of Moser's parabolic harnack inequality using the old ideas of Nash".  Its references might give earlier references.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Hilbert's nineteenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_nineteenth_problem#The_path_to_the_complete_solution) makes mention of a 2D result in the thesis of Sergei Bernstein (1904) and subsequent improvements to it.  Is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @hardmath, obtaining harnack inequality using Nash's idea is a beautiful paper which I have been aware of. Your other reference regarding the thesis of Bernstein is the sort of reference I am looking for.  I am curious if there are any different ideas that existed in proving the digiorgi Nash moser theorem in 2D (something that is independent of the ideas of digiorgi Nash or moser).

Comment: The 2D case is much easier, and the ideas are sort of well-known in the PDE community, but I am not sure of the original work. I gave this as a homework assignment in a course I taught: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~jwcalder/222BS16/hw3_sol.pdf

Comment: @Jeff, Your solution is really nice as it distills the main ideas.

Comment: Thanks. I should say I got the main ideas from a minicourse given by L.C. Evans. The hole-filling trick, in particular, is very nice. It is interesting to examine where the argument would fail for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: I believe the reason $n=2$ works in your proof is essentially because in (5) of your solution, the term $r^2$ in $r^{\lambda+2-n}$ comes because of the ellipticity condition is a quadratic form. This is where the $n=2$ makes life easy. Here is an alternate proof to see this more clearly, using the notion of weakly monotone function "http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02921588", continuity of the solution is trivial. To show H\"older continuity, all one needs to prove is a higher integrability result which is called Meyer's theorem (I seem to not remember the right reference).